# how to achieve the start time of another variable as the end time of the variable coming before it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table here(shown below) that has the phase and the time it ran. What I am trying to accomplish is
to use the time of the phase coming after the previous phase as the end time of the previous phase.

So Right now i have:

```
rownum PhaseName PhaseID      Time                    TimeEnd

 1      Air Removal          2 2016-06-01 11:46:46.000   2016-06-01 11:46:46.000

 2      Heat up              3 2016-06-01 11:56:47.000   2016-06-01 11:56:47.000

 3      Steriliztion         4 2016-06-01 12:06:17.000   2016-06-01 12:06:17.000

 4      Air Pressurization   5 2016-06-01 12:23:40.000   2016-06-01 12:23:40.000

5      Exhaust              6 2016-06-01 12:27:18.000   2016-06-01 12:27:18.000

6      Drying               7 2016-06-01 12:29:35.000   2016-06-01 12:29:35.000

7      Equalization         8 2016-06-01 12:34:36.000   2016-06-01 12:34:36.000
```

And I would like to accomplish this:

```
rownum PhaseName  PhaseID      Time                    TimeEnd

 1      Air Removal          2  2016-06-01 11:46:46.000   2016-06-01 11:56:47.000

 2      Heat up                 3  2016-06-01 11:56:47.000   2016-06-01 12:06:17.000

 3      Steriliztion         4  2016-06-01 12:06:17.000   2016-06-01 12:23:40.000

 4      Air Pressurization   5  2016-06-01 12:23:40.000   2016-06-01 12:27:18.000

 5      Exhaust              6  2016-06-01 12:27:18.000   2016-06-01 12:29:35.000 

 6      Drying               7  2016-06-01 12:29:35.000   2016-06-01 12:34:36.000

 7      Equalization         8  2016-06-01 12:34:36.000   2016-06-01 12:34:36.000
```

-- Last Phase with no End Time...

The Reason for this is, that i have data that is captured during each phase and I am trying to create a SSRS Report that uses the Phase as the Parent group. But My data comes in with the 
phase as a variable already embedded within the captured data. I have used a lot of CTE's to get to a point where i have established when each phase occurs but need to now figure out how to 
achieve the results above.

Comment: you seem to be saying that in your final CTE - let's call it CTE, that you want to do

Comment: Sorry for the bad english, my CTE have gotten me to where I have the start time when each phase occurs. Now i would like to somehow manipulatate my query to also include a column (Time End) that has the time end for each phase. The time end would be the time when the phase coming after the previous phase started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only used these analytical functions in Oracle, but SQL Server has these same functions called LAG and LEAD, where LAG looks at the row before the current row and LEAD looks at the row after the current row.

Here is an example of the syntax, where the function is looking at the past row's TimeEnd and setting it as TimeStart based on PhaseID (or RowID since both are sequential and order the rows the same).

```
SELECT LAG(TimeEnd, 1) OVER (ORDER BY PhaseID) TimeStart
```

Here is some more info on these analytical functions:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

**EDIT:** These functions are only in SQL Server 2012 and onwards, but I have found an article that describes how to mimic these functions in earlier versions of SQL Server using CTEs, like you have been doing: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: Be careful, the OP hasn't stated which version of SQL Server they have. Your answer wouldn't work on versions prior to SQL Server 2012. It would be worth editing your answer and adding the caveat that this will only work for SQL Server 2012 and above.

Comment: Thanks, I will. I also found an article on how to do this in earlier versions of SQL Server, so if OP is using an earlier version, maybe he could use it.

Comment: HEy Thanks guys I used the Lead function to solve most of my issue, there are still errors that i need to address but this issue has been resolved. I also appreciate the two articles one for using the Lead/lag functions and the other article for getting the job done without the two functions. They help because I have a 2014 sql server and also a 2008 sql server both used for different clients. So thanks!

Comment: It's no problem, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @aliaslam: If this solution answer to your question then pleas mark as solved and upvote it.

Comment: I did do an upvote but it errored due to not having a lot of reputation points under my account.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be saying that in your final CTE - let's call it CTE, that you want to do
     ....FROM CTE LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.rownum = CTE2.Rownum+1

to default the bottom right value (which will be null) use COALESCE(CTE2.TimeEnd, CTE1.TimeEnd)